# Having trouble with finding a string in a vector

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with my code. I am taking in a csv file and putting it in a vector, and I want to be able to have the user search for an item. However, for some reason, when I type in the item I am looking for, the code tells me that the item is not in the vector, but it is?

Comment: What does this question have to do with the `GooglePlayApp` class? You could remove that entirely and still have the bug, I think.

Comment: Have you tried printing the values of `userInput` and `allApps.at(i)`?

Comment: @0x5453 I have yes, I can confirm you can find the values in the vector.

Comment: @cigien Yes I agree that the class could probably be left out, I just pasted my entire code just to be sure.

Comment: Then go ahead and remove it. Try and create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with *minimal* being the key aspect here. You might even solve the issue yourself.

Comment: @Mohamed Add some input data details that you have tried.

Comment: @cigien I have made the code shorter. Hopefully this will help.

Comment: @NiVeR I have given an example at the top of my post.

Comment: Much better thanks. You seem to be expecting the input to be separated by `,` but your csv file has spaces.

Comment: @cigien I have provided the contents of my csv file on my post. Hopefully it will be more clear as to why I am using ```,```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getline that populates your vector splits on comma, but not on newline characters. So instead of storing `Little Fire Station`, you're storing `$0.00\nLittle Fire Station`.

You need to read each line individually, and then construct a stringstream from that, and parse that using comma:

```
if (file) {
  while (getline(file, input))
  {
    std::string word;
    std::istringstream line(input);
    while (getline(line, word, ','))
      allApps.push_back(word);
  }
  file.close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It just repeats each line six times in the console.

Comment: Do as I mean, not as I do ;). Alternatively, I was testing you. You need to push back `word`, not `line`. Don't just copy-paste code from stackoverflow. Make sure you understand it before using it. Fixed my typo.

Comment: You'll also need to incorporate cigien's fix from their answer.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allApps.size(); i++) 
{
   if (userInput == allApps.at(i)) 
   {
     // ...
   } 
   else 
   {
      cout << endl << "Application not found." << endl << endl;
      break;
   }
}
```

you are exiting the loop as soon as the first string is not what you are looking for. You need to look at *all* the strings before making that decision. You could do something like:

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < allApps.size(); i++) 
{
   if (userInput == allApps.at(i)) 
   {
     // ...
     found = true;
   } 
}
if (!found)
{
   cout << endl << "Application not found." << endl << endl;
}
```

Or even better, use an algorithm:

```
auto i = std::find(allApps.begin, allApps.end(), userInput);
if (i != allApps.end())
{
  // ...
}
else
{
   cout << endl << "Application not found." << endl << endl;
}
```